# Supremum and infimum of the following set.

Tags: analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I need to find the supremum and infimum of the following set:
$$\Big\lbrace\frac{k-n}{kn}\text{, where k, n }\epsilon\Bbb{N}\Big\rbrace$$
I'm guessing that the supremum is $1$ and infimum is $-1$, but I neither am sure nor know how to prove it.

Comment: Hint: get lim for fixed $k$ , then get lim for fixed $n$

Answer (score 0):

Since $\color{blue}{\sup\{x+y:x\in A, y\in B\}=\sup\{x:x\in A\}+\sup\{y:y\in B\}}$
$$\sup\Big\lbrace\frac{k-n}{kn}\text{, where k, n }\epsilon\Bbb{N}\Big\rbrace=
\sup\Big\lbrace\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{k}\text{, where k, n }\epsilon\Bbb{N}\Big\rbrace=
\sup\Big\lbrace\frac{1}{n}\text{, where k, n }\epsilon\Bbb{N}\Big\rbrace-\inf\Big\lbrace\frac{1}{k}\text{, where k, n }\epsilon\Bbb{N}\Big\rbrace=1-0=1$$
Similar way shows $\inf=-1$.

Comment: okay, but why? Where does that come from? @MyGlasses